Content Version before trigger data inconsistency issue
I have a before update trigger on content version to update the data of notes object in apex . It is working sometimes but sometimes in the before update the new updated value is not showing . For now I have switched the trigger to after trigger and It's working. Is this the issue from salesforce or I am doing something wrong.
The code for before update :
     public static void updateTitleOnUpdate(List<ContentVersion> listOfNotesToUpdate,map<Id,ContentVersion> oldMap,map<Id,ContentVersion> newMap){
            try{
                
            Set<Id> listOfContentDocumentIds = new Set<Id>();
            Map<Id,ContentVersion> mapOfContentDocumentWithContentVersion = new Map<Id,ContentVersion>();
                Map<Id,ContentVersion> mapOfContentDocumentWithContentVersionToUpdate = new Map<Id,ContentVersion>();
                //List<ContentVersion> listOfContentVersionToUpdate = new List<ContentVersion>();
            Map<Id,Id> mapOfContentDocumentIsWithLinkedEntityId = new Map<Id,Id>();
                 List<ContentVersion> listOfContentVersionToUpdate = new List<ContentVersion>();
            for(ContentVersion c : listOfNotesToUpdate){
                //check to insert notes only
                if(c.FileType == 'SNOTE'){
                    
                    listOfContentDocumentIds.add(c.contentDocumentId);
                    mapOfContentDocumentWithContentVersion.put(c.contentDocumentId,c);
                    mapOfContentDocumentWithContentVersionToUpdate.put(c.contentDocumentId,c);
                    
                }
            }
            if(!listOfContentDocumentIds.isEmpty()){
                for(ContentDocumentLink cdl : [SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId, Visibility, IsDeleted, ShareType, ContentDocument.Title, ContentDocument.createdDate, ContentDocument.FileType, LinkedEntity.type FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId =:listOfContentDocumentIds]){
                    system.debug('newVersionData3==');
                    //make update only on Account object 
                    if(cdl.LinkedEntity.type == 'Account'){
                        mapOfContentDocumentIsWithLinkedEntityId.put(cdl.LinkedEntityId,cdl.ContentDocumentId);
                    }  
                }
                List<contentVersion> newContentVersions = new List<contentVersion>();
                if(!mapOfContentDocumentIsWithLinkedEntityId.isEmpty()){
                    system.debug('newVersionData4==');
                    //Campaign activeCampaign =   [SELECT Id, Name, IsActive FROM Campaign WHERE IsActive = True];
                    for(Id cdl : mapOfContentDocumentIsWithLinkedEntityId.keySet()){
                                            system.debug('newVersionData5==');
                   //    mapOfContentDocumentWithContentVersion.get(mapOfContentDocumentIsWithLinkedEntityId.get(cdl)).title = activeCampaign.Name;
                        blob versionD =  mapOfContentDocumentWithContentVersion.get(mapOfContentDocumentIsWithLinkedEntityId.get(cdl)).versionData;
                       
                        if(versionD != null){
                            String newVersionData = versionD.toString() + String.valueOf(UserInfo.getFirstName() != null ? UserInfo.getFirstName().substring(0,1) : '') + String.valueOf(UserInfo.getLastName().substring(0,1) +' '+ String.valueOf(System.now().format('MM/dd/yy hh:mm a')));
   mapOfContentDocumentWithContentVersion.get(mapOfContentDocumentIsWithLinkedEntityId.get(cdl)).versionData = Blob.valueOf(newVersionData);                         
                          
                        }
                         system.debug('listOfContentVersionToUpdate=='+listOfContentVersionToUpdate);
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
            catch(Exception e ){
            system.debug('exception==='+e.getMessage());
        }
        }


Strange behaviour came across to me , The trigger is not firing  sometimes  , on idea why is this happening?

You need to capture a debug log and try to replicate the before-update issue, then you will have more information.
